# How to find a good sweet potato fry cutter?

Tags: equipment, sweet-potatoes

I am looking to make my own sweet potato fries, however sweet potatoes are harder to cut than regular potatoes.

Even more expensive cutters such as the [Nemco N554503](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/nemco-n554503-easy-frykutter-1-2-heavy-duty-french-fry-cutter/591N554503.html) fry cutter are not recommended for cutting sweet potatoes.

Does anyone know what makes a cutter suitable for sweet potato fries?

Comment: [Here's one](http://www.chefscatalog.com/product/25871-restaurant-french-fry-cutter.aspx) that claims to be [but this video begs to differ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d2LWXW4TLY)

Comment: Shopping recommendations asking for the "best" brand are not allowed, I had to edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the [Progressive International Jumbo Potato Cutter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002KZ4VI) and it works well for sweet potato fries. The product spec for them lists "Yams" which are sometimes what sweet potatoes are called in the U.S. (technically, yes, yams are different but real yams are not often available in the U.S.). The [LEM Products Commercial French Fry Cutter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002L7V1B2) specifically lists sweet potatoes:

> Makes French fries, sweet potato fries, zucchini sticks and other
>   favorites

Comment: The LEM cutter looks promising, I will give it a try.

Comment: Note that looks an awful lot like the [Weston fry cutter](http://www.amazon.com/Weston-Restaurant-Quality-French-Cutter/dp/B000T3OO8C/ref=pd_sim_sg_1) from the [video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d2LWXW4TLY) in my original comment. While the Weston doesn't specifically call out sweet potatoes, it does seem to be the same mechanism.

Comment: I realize this is an older post but I wanted to voice my comment on the sweet potato cutter you listed."Progressive International Jumbo Potato Cutter" DO NOT BUY THIS PIECE OF EQUIPMENT!! It specifically states not for yams or sweet potatos. I find it difficult to believe that you actually sliced sweet potatoes using this tool. Don't waste your money people on this if you want to slice sweet potatoes.

Comment: That’s interesting, this product does indeed say both “for yams and sweet potatoes” as well as “NOT FOR YAMS AND SEEET POTATOES”. I am guessing that as people returned them broken that they updated a part of their literature but failed to update the other part.

Answer (score 3):

Ziggy's Potato Cutters will handle sweet potatoes...they are harder on the blade but it does a fine job. www.ribbonfries.biz

Comment: Although we don't normally want self-promotion, I think in this case given that the top voted accepted answer basically just lists two brands and links to them, I can't really justify deleting this as spam. It's also indirectly helpful, in that it suggests that ribbon fries rather than traditional fries are easier for sweet potatoes.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve the operation of the sweet potato cutter by microwaving the potato for about a minute and cutting off the ends to square it up against the blade. And don't try to cut with one push.  Rather a series of less forceful pushes pressuring the potato a little bit at a time.   Don't be afraid to use PAM on the blades to reduce friction.  Good luck.

Comment: +1, while I disagree about the use of the microwave the rest of the answer is solid and does work.

Answer (score 1):

Most varieties of sweet potato will not successfully chip, or hold together during the cooking process when chipped into the traditional square rod shape. Sweet potato turns mushy very quickly during the cooking process, and may also go very chewy if even slightly over cooked

Commercial sweet potato chips have been carefully selected and pre-cooked to hold shape and maintain strength for the a quick hot oil fry finish. Frozen sweet potato chips are generally intended for cooking in the oven

I would suggest you experiment with different sized discs cut from the width of the sweet potato. Using an adjustable depth [Mandoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandoline) will help with this

[image: Sweet potato discs]
[image: Sweet potato deep fried]